# html sites are fast but cms (wordpress/magento) sites are slow on my server. I cant find the reason

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, hosting, shared

html sites are fast but cms (WordPress/magento) sites are slow on my server. I cant find the reason. This is my default WordPress site without theme and any plugins. Just installed. http://www.googlecloudhost.com/. It took 90+ seconds to load but this html site http://sohamdistributors.com/. This takes less than 2 seconds to load.

Please help me to find the reason of slow cms site.

Comment: Verify PHP and MySQL performance on your server...

Comment: My site doesn't have any plugin as of now as I said. Its a default installation. And using W3 Total and WP Super Cache is secondary matter. My question is if my server takes 20+ seconds to respond then why they respond fast for html sites. I know WP and other cms have database. But when I execute any query on phpmyadmin it takes .02 second. It means database is not slowing down the response time. And other websites (Not in my re-seller account) is also hosted on the same server but they are loading fine. Server admin is telling no issue is at their end. Any other tests to diagnose the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sites using WordPress/Magento are slower than sites using static HTML because of PHP and database usage. Your site on googlecloudhost.com seems slower than it should be though, it takes 20+ seconds for the server to respond.

To make sure the problem is not caused by a plugin you are using on your website you can use the [Plugin Performance Profiler plugin for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/).

To increase performance you can also use a caching plugin like [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache).

If both options do not solve your problem consider consulting your hosting provider, the problem could be caused by their setup then.

Comment: My site doesn't have any plugin as of now as I said. Its a default installation. And using W3 Total and WP Super Cache is secondary matter. My question is if my server takes 20+ seconds to respond then why they respond fast for html sites. I know WP and other cms have database. But when I execute any query on phpmyadmin it takes .02 second. It means database is not slowing down the response time. And other websites (Not in my re-seller account) is also hosted on the same server but they are loading fine. Server admin is telling no issue is at their end. Any other tests to diagnose the issue?